# Socket Datastream transfer to other activity

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio-3.0

I'm doing a socket programming where client has 2 activities. And different types of data from the server are used to be displayed on both the activities. I created a socket in the first activity, opened the Inputdatastream and then transferred the socket to the second activity using standard Socket Handler class. But when I open the InputDatastream in the second, I'm not getting any data there. Please suggest me some solution. 
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> order = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> details = new HashMap<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);
    if(!(total>0.0)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener =
        new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
                        ipToset,
                        Integer.parseInt(portToset));
                myClientTask.execute();
            }};

public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";

    MyClientTask(String addr, int port) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            SocketHandler.setSocket(socket);
            if(total>0.0) {

                SocketClientReplyThread socketClientReplyThread = new SocketClientReplyThread(
                        socket, "from client");
                socketClientReplyThread.run();

                SocketClientReadThread socketClientReadThread = new SocketClientReadThread(
                        socket, "from client");
                socketClientReadThread.run();
            }

            if(total>0.0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), OrderSummary.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {

            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (clientSocket != null) {
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class SocketClientReadThread extends Thread {
    private Socket hostThreadSocket;

    String message;

    SocketClientReadThread(Socket socket, String c) {
        hostThreadSocket = socket;
        message = c;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        OutputStream outputStream;

        try {

            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hostThreadSocket.getInputStream()));
            response= inFromServer.readLine();

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textResponse.setText(response);
                }
            });

            response= inFromServer.readLine();


            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textResponse.setText(response);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }
    }
}
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
  public class OrderSummary extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView prep;
    TextView pack;
    TextView ready;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_summary);

    TextView prep = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preparing);
    TextView pack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.packaging);
    TextView ready = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ready);
    ready.setText("predators");

    OrderSummary.MyTask myTask = new OrderSummary.MyTask();
    myTask.execute();

}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        System.out.println("background");
        try {
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(SocketHandler.getSocket().getInputStream()));

            final String prep1 = inFromServer.readLine();
            final String pack1 = inFromServer.readLine();
            final String ready1 = inFromServer.readLine();
            OrderSummary.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    prep.setText(prep1);
                    pack.setText(pack1);
                    ready.setText("predators");
                }
            });


        }catch(IOException e){}

        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

Log when i click connect button:

```
04-22 06:58:33.415 28714-28725/? I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 4134(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 958KB/2MB, paused 4.538ms total 246.184ms
04-22 06:59:36.811 28714-28725/com.example.ashwa.testclient I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 277(277KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 79.877ms total 1.690s
04-22 06:59:37.308 28714-29208/com.example.ashwa.testclient I/System.out: background
```

Comment: can you provide some code that you tried and the result that you are getting?

Comment: @RakibulHaq Please check the code part edited. I have posted only the relevant part. Code compiles and runs correctly, but I can't see any output in my activity screen.  Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the `logcat` logs when you are pressing connect button? also for curiosity, why are you sending data from one `activity` to another in the same app using `socket`?

Comment: @RakibulHaq I am getting the data from the server, code of which I have not posted here. Only one part of the data is to be displayed in the first activity and the rest to go into the second. I just tried to transfer the socket object and open a new datastream to read, but failed. I found the solution for this, this question is already answered. Thanks a lot Rakibul.

Comment: I found the solution to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720327/multiple-threads-reading-from-same-socket. This question is a duplicate. Please go to this link.

Comment: There is no such thing as either a `DataStream` or an `InputDatastream` in Java, and no evidence here that you are using any such thing. Also no evidence here of any output to the socket.

Comment: Thanks @King Klang for the edits. I'm new to this website.